# Two Mono in Unity3d, which is in used?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono, monodevelop

I just found there are two mono after you finished install the Unity3D.

One is in Unity.app and the other is in Monodevelop.app.

I even found this two mono are different

```
mingchaoyan at mingchaoyan_mac in /tmp/testcs $
/Applications/Unity/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.0/bin/mcs HelloWorld.cs

mingchaoyan at mingchaoyan_mac in /tmp/testcs $     
/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono/bin/mcs HelloWorld.cs
The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded. 
It should have been installed in the `/Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/tmp/monoprefix/lib/mono/1.0/mscorlib.dll' directory.
```

So, My question are:

1. Why the one in Unity.app report this error? If I want to solve this,
       How?
2. Why there are two different mono?
3. Which one is Unity3D actually used ?
4. If I want to build a dll to use in Unity3D, Which one Should I use?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different Mono versions because they are 2 different applications both supplying their own dependencies. In the case of Unity you generally don't have to worry about it. You won't be compiling with MonoDevelop anyway. In the end it's Unity which will compile your code as part of its own build process.

That also answers your 3rd question: Unity uses its own Mono dependencies.

However, in your case, if you want to build a DLL to be used inside Unity, you can use MonoDevelop just fine. Just compile and write a DLL as you normally would, but make sure to reference the UnityEngine library if you use any of its functionality. A [tutorial such as this one](http://yeticrabgames.blogspot.ch/2014/03/creating-dll-in-monodevelop.html) should help you out, but there is plenty more information out there.

As for your first question, I don't have a direct answer, but that's not really how you will be using Mono with Unity anyway.

Comment: In case of build a dll, I just worry about the dll can't be used by Unity because of the different versions?(Monodevelop uses 4.x but Unity just uses 2.x).

Comment: Just make sure you select a proper target framework within Monodevelop. I think you should be able to push it up to 3.5 in the general build settings.